# Remove all numbers except the first using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

Basically what I have to do is to remove all digits and leave the first one. If it's a number under 10 keep that number.

I already made some code but instead of removing all digits following the first, I removed the first digit.

My code:

```
public static int keepFirstDigit(int num) {
  // Can't change anything besides the following code
  if(num==0){
    return 0;
  }
  if(num>0){
    return num % (int) Math.pow(10, (int) Math.log10(num));
  }
  return num;
}
```

If the number is 5, the output should be 5.
If the number is 23 the output should be 2.
If the number is 62363456 the output should be 6.

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: My code is not returning the first digit. It's returning every digit after the first one. What I want is the first digit only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to understand what is recursion and how it works.
Recursion means function/method call itself.
in below program removeDigit method calling itself if n is greater than 10 with n = n/10.

try this one.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(removeDigit(23219));
    }

    public static int removeDigit(int n) {
        if (Math.abs(n) < 10) {
            return n;
        } 
        return removeDigit(n/10);
    }
}
```

for n = 23219

iteration 1

23219 > 10 
call removeDigit with n = 23219/10 = 2321

iteration 2

2321 > 10 
call removeDigit with n = 2321/10 = 232

iteration 3

232 > 10 
call removeDigit with n = 232/10 = 23

iteration 4

23 > 10 
call removeDigit with n = 23/10 = 2

iteration 5

2 < 10 
So return 2

Comment: This worked! It was so simple and I was having problems... Thank you.

Comment: Note that I don't think it handle negative values.

Comment: @el-teedee thanks for pointing out the issues. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if recursion is the best tool to do it however this should work :

```
    public static int keepFirstDigit(int num) {


        //Can't change anything besides the following code
       if(num < 10) {
           return num;
       } else {
           return keepFirstDigit(num / 10);
       }
    }
```

If `num` is less then 10 we jest return it. Otherwise we divide `num` by `10` without the remainder and pass it to recursive method call.

For negative numbers we could change the negative number to positive as this does not affect first digit :

```
    public static int keepFirstDigit(int num) {

        num = Math.abs(num);

       if(num < 10) {
           return num;
       } else {
           return keepFirstDigit(num / 10);
       }
    }
```

We could also do the `abs` before calling this method and pass it as parameter.

Comment: Note that I don't think it handle negative values.

Comment: Yep you are right, but the quick solution would be to add `num = Math.abs(num)` or just do the `abs` outside of the recursive call. For negative number the first digit does not change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you need to do it recursiveley but if you don't, I'd do it like this

```java
public static int keepFirstDigit(int num) {
  String tempNum = String.valueOf(num).substring(0,1);
  return((int) Integer.parseInt(tempNum));
}
```

but if you do, just use the other examples that have already been posted

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved using Strings, maybe think of this:

```
public static int keepFirstDigit(int num) {
   //Can't change anything besides the following code
   return Integer.parseInt((num+"").charAt(0)+"");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Pankaj Singh and @michalk answer, here is a working, verifiable solution in Javascript.
It also handle negative and null values.
Run it to see output and results.
(Probably not the fastest, shortest way though)

```
Result for 0 -> 0
Result for 10 -> 1
Result for -10 -> -1
Result for 9.9999 -> 9
Result for 1.57 -> 1
Result for 23 -> 2
Result for 34.5 -> 3
Result for 5678848 -> 5
Result for -3.14159 -> -3
Result for -28.123 -> -2
```

```js
// Define a function doing the job
// Take an object as argument, not a number (for updating purpose)
const getFirstDigit = (obj) => {
  // Ensure argument is valid
  if (!obj || !obj.count) {
    return;
  }
  if ((obj.count >= 0 && obj.count < 10) 
    /* handle negatives */
    || (obj.count <= 0 && obj.count > -10)) {
    // Ensure it is an integer
    obj.count = parseInt(obj.count);
  } else {
    // Divide by ten: update obj.count
    obj.count = parseInt(obj.count / 10);
    // Recursion: call again since number is greater or equals than 10
    getFirstDigit(obj);
  }
}
// At the end of recursion stack, obj.count will be an integer < 10 == the first digit of initial number

// Give some inputs (and negative values)
let numbers = [0, 10, -10, 9.9999, 1.57, 23, 34.50, 5678848, -3.14159, -28.123];

for (index in numbers) {
  let input = numbers[index];
  // Prepare an object to hold our number
  let object = { count: input };
  // Call the method by passing an object
  // Passing an object rather a primitive Number allow the function to update the object by reference
  getFirstDigit(object)
  // Retrieve object updated (or not) number
  let output = object.count;
  console.log(`Result for ${input} -> ${output}`);
}
```